# How to make http requests to your web api hosted in iis from your phone's browser

Tags: android, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to make web API requests to my asp.net core 2.2 web API that is hosted in IIS. I can get back results when I use 'example.com:50056/api/Vehicle/GetCarpaint' from my browser. However, I get 'This site can't be reached' when I make the same request from my mobile phone's browser. Even when I use the IP address of my the machine where the website is hosted. My pc and phone are both on the same network.

Below, I wrote down my finding to this whole situation.

BROWSER

- example.com --OK
- example.com:50056/api/Vehicle/GetCarpaint --OK (getting back data)
- http://192.168.8.X:50056 --Error 400 Bad Request -Invalid Hostname
- http://192.168.8.X:50056/api/Vehicle/GetCarpaint --Error 400 Bad Request -Invalid Hostname

PHONE'S BROWSER

- http://192.168.8.X --OK
- http://192.168.8.X/api/Vehicle/GetCarpaint --Error 404 File or directory not found
- http://192.168.8.X:50056 --Error 400 Bad Request -Invalid Hostname
- http://192.168.8.X:50056/api/Vehicle/GetCarpaint --Error 400 Bad Request -Invalid Hostname
- example.com --This site can't be reached, drsmashservices.com's server IP address could not be found
- example.com/api/Vehicle/GetCarpaint --This site can't be reached, example.com's server IP     address could not be found

I expected to type the IP address of the site with my port followed by my route however my phone's browser can't seem to find the DNS of my website, additionally, I added an inbound rule with port 50056 and I still can't get it to work, am I missing something?

Comment: You simply missed the fact that you need to study DNS and how to configure your phone to use the right settings. Those are not topics covered by Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will look right into it